# CASE WHEN in GROUP BY SQL Expression

Tags: sql, select, group-by, case

I have this simple question: given Query 1 (Q1) and Query 2 (Q2):

Q1:

```sql
select      case when [A] is null then [B] else [A] end,
            sum([X])
from        TABLE_ABX
group by    case when [A] is null then [B] else [A] end;
```

Q2:

```sql
select      case when [A] is null then [B] else [A] end,
            sum([X])
from        TABLE_ABX
group by    [A], [B];
```

Would those two SQL queries always be equivalent?

It's more of theoretical question. Not trying any specific query at the moment.

Comment: You could of course just pop over to your favorite DBFiddle and verify the behaviour in a couple of minutes.

Comment: `case when [A] is null then [B] else [A] end` is pretty much the definition of  `coalesce(A, B)`.

Answer (score 4):

The queries are not equivalent. The easiest way to show this with a counter-example:

| a | b | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 |

Since `b` is never `null`, the expression `case when [A] is null then [B] else [A] end` always returns `a`, or `1` for both rows.

In the first query, since this expression is in the `group by` clause, you'll get one row in the result, with a sum of `30`.
In the second query, since the combination of `a` and `b` is grouped by, you'll get two rows in the result, one with `10` and one with `20`.